# How to get active application path with known name in cmd

Tags: python, cmd

I know the name of an application (in my case it's AfterFX.exe) and it is open and running on Windows... is there a way to get the path to that application in a python script (or command prompt argument using `subprocess`)?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://superuser.com/questions/768984/show-exe-file-path-of-running-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Comment: That's it! Thank you @zedfoxus!